# Can't execute program from the source code even though the compiling process had no error and warnings(Dev C++)

Tags: c++

```
Source Code :
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    char huruf;
    char nama[]="Muhammad Juan Syarin";
    int usia, berat, tinggi;
    int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
 
   huruf='M';usia=19;berat=68;tinggi=170;
   printf("Huruf depan : %s", huruf);
   printf("Nama Lengkap : %s", nama);
   printf("Usia : %d", usia);
   printf("\nBerat : %d", berat);
   printf("\nTinggi : %d", tinggi);
   printf("\nNilai ke-7 dari Array (77,78,80,81,82,83,85,89) adalah %i", arr[7]);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

I tried to change the value and the variable and to be true i don't know what to do since this is the very first time i try to learn how to make a source code.I hope some guidance for this newbies.

Comment: I get some compilation errors - live - https://godbolt.org/z/Yzo6TdTf4

Comment: @RichardCritten owh maybe the dev c++ can't detect this kind of error i think.(edit) Oops my bad i forgot to put the ; on the array at end;

Comment: @MuhammadJuanSyarin Also note, that `conio.h` isn't a standard header and you're even not using anything from it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i don't know anything i just follow my teacher's guide book, thanks for telling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a semicolon while defining the array. Also the format specifier in the first printf statement is for strings, not characters. Replace the %s there with %c. So in change line 10 to int `arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};` and replace `%s` in line 13 to `%c`

Comment: Like this? 

'code'
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char huruf;
    char nama[]="Muhammad Juan Syarin";
    int usia, berat, tinggi;
    int arr[8] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    huruf='M';
    usia=19;
    berat=68;
    tinggi=170;
    printf("%c\n", huruf);
    printf("Nama Lengkap : %c", nama);
    printf("Usia : %d", usia);
    printf("\nBerat : %d", berat);
    printf("\nTinggi : %d", tinggi);
    printf("\nNilai ke-7 dari Array (77,78,80,81,82,83,85,89) adalah %i", arr[7]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}